# versions-maven-plugin:update-property not updating pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-versions-plugin

Hi Meier I have used the following goal:

```
mvn versions:update-property
    -Dproperty="emom.web.dependency.shr.version"
    -Dincludes:org.safeway.com:emom-shr
    -DgenerateBackupPoms=false
    -DallowIncrementalVersios=true
    -DallowSnapshots=true
    clean package
```

My Job B pom.xml is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.safeway.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>emom-shr</artifactId>
  <version>${emom.web.dependency.shr.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Under the properties it has the version hard-coded:

```
<emom.web.dependency.shr.version>19.6.5-SNAPSHOT</emom.web.dependency.shr.version>
```

My Job A pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.safeway.app</groupId>
<artifactId>emom-shr</artifactId>
<version>20.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

When I run the above goal, Maven is picking the latest version (i.e. 20.1.0) from Artifactory but when I check the pom.xml of Job B under properties it still says 19.6.5. I need a way to change the 19.6.5 or current version to latest version available. Am I doing something wrong? I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Is it a typo that you have 'Dproperty=emom.web.dependency.shr.version' with no leading hyphen '-D'?

Comment: Hello Ben, My bad it's a typo actually                                                                                                mvn versions:update-property  -Dproperty="emom.web.dependency.shr.version" -Dincludes:org.safeway.com:emom-shr  -DgenerateBackupPoms=false -DallowIncrementalVersios=true -DallowSnapshots=true clean package'                           I'm using the goals like this

Comment: Ah OK and -DallowIncrementalVersios=true, do you mean -DallowIncrementalUpdates=true?

Comment: Yes Ben, not sure if I'm not following the correct proccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of `versions-maven-plugin:update-property` working in practice. I've used the common Mockito library as an example that works for everyone as it's in Maven Central.

Starting with this POM (noting the `mockito-version` property):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>def</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <mockito-version>2.22.0</mockito-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

The simplest way to upgrade it to the latest release version is this:

```
mvn versions:update-property -Dproperty=mockito-version
```

Replace `mockito-version` with `emom.web.dependency.shr.version` in your case.

You can then start to use more of the [goal options](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-property-mojo.html) to adjust the options. For example, you might:

- Permit snapshots, not just releases, with `-DallowSnapshots=true`.
- Disallow major version updates (i.e. third element from the right) with `-DallowMajorUpdates=false`. Note that the logic around these version number sections seems a bit flaky in the plugin - or isn't how I expect.
- Avoid creating backup POMs with `-DgenerateBackupPoms=false`. This is cleaner, but if you omit this option then you can use `mvn versions:revert` to get yourself back to where you started.

To apply this to your scenario, I think you need to:

- Check you've not got typos in your actual command (like you have in the question and comments).
- Get rid of options that don't appear in the [options](https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-property-mojo.html).
- Probably, keep things simple by not trying to run this in conjunction with anything else (unless it's in automation), so get rid of the `clean package` at the end of the command.

Comment: Thanks Ben  now I can see my pom file is been updated with latest version there was a typo on my goals, I was being stupid should have realized earlier.

Comment: Good to hear you got there. If you're happy that my answer fixed your question, please mark it with the check/tick on the left so future users know it works.